# create circles on a spline

Tags: matlab, spline

I need a little information regarding creation of elements in the form of either circles or Hexagon along the entire spline as shown in below image in Matlab. Can you tell me how can i implement this in my code.

[image]

Please find the below code with respect to spline creation

```
x = -4:4;
y = [0 .15 1.12 2.36 2.36 1.46 .49 .06 0];
cs = spline(x,[0 y 0]);
xx = linspace(-4,4,101);
plot(x,y,'o',xx,ppval(cs,xx),'-');
```

Please let me know incase any additional information is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since you already know the locations at which you want to plot the circles  (the `[x,y]` array) you can replicate part of the `plot` code you used but this time use larger markers and a different color:

```
hold on
plot(x,y,'o',xx,ppval(cs,xx),'-');
plot(x,y,'o','MarkerSize',80,'Color','g');
```

which looks like this:
[image]

You can use the 'hexagram' marker as well (i.e. use `h` instead of `o`) to get an hexagon:

[image]

Or if you want each circle to look different or control their properties individually you can also plot a rectangle with a curvature of `[1 1]`:

```
radius = .5; 

for k = 1:numel(x)
centerX = x(k);
centerY = y(k);
rectangle('Position',[centerX - radius, centerY - radius, radius*2, radius*2],...
    'Curvature',[1 1],...
    'EdgeColor','g','FaceColor','none');
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. It was very helpful and can I plot octagon as well similar to hexagon and if yes, which code should I use similar to 'h' for hexagon

Comment: You're welcome! I'm afraid I don't know how to plot an octagon easily. You can check Matlab's documentation [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linespec.html) about line markers and how to modify them

Comment: Thank you. I will check it.